# Gradle does not copy test resources to build

Tags: java, resources, gradle

I have a multi project gradle project (spring web), with the following layout:

```
springweb
 |    build.gradle
 |    settings.gradle
 |_____ services
 |         build.gradle
 |         src/main/java
 |         src/main/resources
 |         src/test/java
 |         src/test/resources
 |             create-data.sql
 |_____ web
 |         build.gradle
 |         src/main/java
 |         src/main/resources
 |         src/main/webapp
 |         src/test/java
 |         src/test/resources
```

When I try to execute the contents under src/test/resources (init.sql)

```
commandLine 'psql', '-h', 'localhost', '-d', 'junit', '--username', 'junit', '-f' , sourceSets['test'].output.resourcesDir.toString() + '/create-data.sql'
```

it failse because the resource is not available in the build directory:

```
/Users/me/dev/springweb/services/build/resources/test/create-data.sql: No such file or directory
```

below my root build.gradle:

```
ext {
    springSecurityGroup = 'org.springframework.security'
    springSecurityVersion = '3.1.4.RELEASE'
    springGroup = 'org.springframework'
    springVersion = '3.2.5.RELEASE'
    hibernateGroup = 'org.hibernate'
    hibernateVersion = '4.2.7.SP1'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    sourceSets.all{
        println output.classesDir
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and the 'services' build.gradle:

```
task createDb (type:Exec) { 
     println sourceSets['test'].output.resourcesDir.toString()
     commandLine 'psql', '-h', 'localhost', '-d', 'junit', '--username', 'junit', '-f' ,'/Users/me/dev/sip/sip/sip04/src/main/resources/create-table.sql'
}
task fillDb (type:Exec, dependsOn: 'createDb') {
     commandLine 'psql', '-h', 'localhost', '-d', 'junit', '--username', 'junit', '-f' , sourceSets['test'].output.resourcesDir.toString() + '/create-data.sql'
}
test.dependsOn fillDb

dependencies {
    /* zipped */
}

/* Change context path (base url). otherwise defaults to name of project */
```

I execute it with gradle build:

```
gradle build
/Users/me/dev/springweb/services/build/classes/main
/Users/me/dev/springweb/services/build/classes/test
/Users/me/dev/springweb/web/build/classes/main
/Users/me/dev/springweb/web/build/classes/test
/Users/me/dev/springweb/services/build/resources/test
:services:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:services:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:services:classes UP-TO-DATE
:services:jar UP-TO-DATE
:services:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:services:createDb
DROP TABLE
DROP SEQUENCE
zipped
:services:fillDb/Users/me/dev/springweb/services/build/resources/test/create-data.sql: No such file or directory
```

From the output I learn that the sourceSets are as I expect, but that the test resources are not copied. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying of test resources is done by the processTestResources task from the Java plugin. The Java plugin also specifies this as a prerequisite of the test task, so that it happens before the tests are run.

You have told gradle that your fillDb task is also a prerequisite of the test task BUT you have not told it that processTestResources is a prerequisite of your createDb task.

So you could do something like

```
task createDb (type:Exec, dependsOn: 'processTestResources') { 
...
```

BTW test resources are things that are made available to the tests via the classpath. I assume your tests don't need actually your sql available on the classpath at runtime, so do they even need to be there?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your explanation. If I understand you correctly declaring a prerequisite yourself on an existing, breaks the dependency hierarchy introduced by the (java) plugin?I have the idea that the easiest way to make tasks platform independent is to place *all* resources on the classpath. Maybe an alternative would be to introduce an sql sourceset?

Comment: No, declaring a new prerequisite is a totally fine thing to do. You didn't break the java plugin heirachy. processTestResources would still have run before the tests, it was just that gradle didn't know that processTestResources ALSO had to run before createDb. It only knew  that createDb (and fillDb) needed to run before the tests, so it ran createDb first and bailed when it failed (before ever running processTestResources)

Answer (score 2):

Gradle uses `processTestResources` task from the `java` plugin to generate the test resources. By default the location of the test resources in `Module/build/resources/test`. 
If you want to test just the testResources getting generated correctly or not
Run the following command:

```
./gradlew :<Module-name>:processTestResources
```

After running the command, check testReources directory. It should contain the correct files.

**Another Suggestion**
Try Segregating all the common logic in a gradle plugin and write a test for Gradle plugin. In that way, you can get confidence over the piece of code. If it works fine or not.

Eg: 
**TestPlugin.groovy**

```
 project.sourceSets {
            test {
                resources {
                    srcDir project.files("${project.projectDir}/<location-of-resources>/")
                }
            }
        }
```

In this scenario, place your resources in some folder named  and `tempFile` is the resource for test.
And the Test for the same: **TestPluginSpec.groovy**

```
 @Rule
    TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder()
    File tempFile
    tempFile = testProjectDir.newFile('tempFile')
    buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')

    buildFile << """
             plugins {
                id 'java'
               }
   """
def "should add test Resources into build/resources/test"(){
        when:
        def result = GradleRunner.create().withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root).withPluginClasspath().withArguments('processTestResources').withDebug(true).build()
        then:
        result.task(":processTestResources").outcome == TaskOutcome.SUCCESS
        and:
        Files.exists(Paths.get("${testProjectDir.root.path}/build/resources/test/tempFile"))
    }
```